# problem in retrieving the rows in case of composite key through hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have faced this issue many times but couldn't find the solution any where.

My question is that how can i retrieve a tuple or a row in the database through hibernate call,

For example in the relation Student_course(sid,sname,cid,cname, duration)
here sid and cid are considered as the composite key.

please let me know the solution.

Thanks In Adv,
A.Raghavendra

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Mapping file as below,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class
        name="com.example.StudentCourse"
        table="Student_course">
        <composite-id> 
         <key-many-to-one name="student" class="com.example.Student" column="student_ID"/>    
         <key-many-to-one name="course" class="com.example.Course" column="course_ID"/>     
    </composite-id> 
    ///Other mappings elements
```

In the java, if you retrive the List of Student course you can get the details.